# 404 Not Found Images Spring MVC JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to return a JSP from a Spring-MVC controller. While everything else is working fine; images and jquery is not getting loaded properly. Below is my configuration.

```
web.xml
*************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            version="3.0">
    <display-name>Real-App</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml is as below:

```
<mvc:resources  mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my JSP, I am loading images using the below code.

Images:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/SomeImage.png" />" alt="" />
```

jQuery:

```
<c:url var="jq" value="/resources/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${jq}"></script>
```

Both are not working and I am seeing the below messages in the Chrome debugger.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/Real-App/resources/images/SomeImage.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8080/Real-App/resources/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Best Regards,
Mouli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your dispatcher url-pattern is **/**, spring will look for `@RequestMapping` for all the URL's, you need to use the `mvc:resources` tag for excluding from this

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Ramesh, this answer provided the tip to check the folder structure once again. While there were no errors in the mapping, I was mistakenly placed the resources folder inside the WEB-INF folder instead of the maven project webapp folder. Error got resolved after moving the resources folder to webapp folder. Thank you.